# Applying transparency after 50% on a 45deg rotated element

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-transforms

Here's a block element containing a passage. Let's call it * *Block A* *
[image]

I want to add an arrow-tip on top of it, which I did:
[image]

Using the following CSS:

```
.Block_A:before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 50%;
   width: 1em; height: 1em;
   background: #0080FF;
   border-width: 1px 0 0 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #0080FF;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

But as you can see, the text on the passage "died in" got hidden behind the tip. For a better view and understanding, I colored the bottom-half portion of the tip red which shows up over the text of the passage:

[image]

Now how I can keep the top-half portion of the tip blue as it is, but make the bottom-half portion (aka, the red portion) transparent? Like this:
[image]

I tried using:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0080ff 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%);
```

But it didn't work the way it normally does because the shape of the tip is not square or rectangle because I have transformed it (rotated by 45 degree).

Comment: Try putting a low z-index on the :before element then a higher z-index on the .block_a, that might solve your problem.

Comment: Are webkit-linear-gradient, moz-linear-gradient, etc. providing same results?

Comment: @RustyRoberts I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: @drive235 I do not know. I haven't tried that. But it should provide the same result by the above code, because they all are the same more-or-less.

Answer (score 6):

Why not use a triangular shape to begin with? like

```
 #triangle-up { 
   width: 0;
   height: 0; 
   border-left: 50px solid transparent;
   border-right: 50px solid transparent; 
   border-bottom: 100px solid #0080FF; 
 }
```

Check out http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/.

Comment: ah, 20 seconds before me :D

Comment: We can do so much now with CSS3. Why use numerous lines of codes when we can achieve it in one line of CSS3 code?

Comment: @Paranoid because it is best practice to use something basic that works well with more browsers

Comment: You'll end up with much more code using your method. You'll have to use the vendor prefixes for both your transform and your gradient.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rotating rectangle why not try to create a simple triangle, like this:

HTML

```
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
```

CSS

```
.arrow-up {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}
```

**EDIT based on author's comment --------------**

Ok, if you don't bother about IE this background value should do the trick:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,128,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,128,255,1) 49%, rgba(0,128,255,0.01) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,128,255,1)), color-stop(49%,rgba(0,128,255,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(0,128,255,0.01)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,128,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,128,255,1) 49%,rgba(0,128,255,0.01) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,128,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,128,255,1) 49%,rgba(0,128,255,0.01) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,128,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,128,255,1) 49%,rgba(0,128,255,0.01) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,128,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,128,255,1) 49%,rgba(0,128,255,0.01) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0080ff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Simple demo - http://jsfiddle.net/LH69Q/

p.s. You can modify the gradient just by generating it yourself from here - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: We can do so much now with CSS3. Why stay outdated and use numerous lines of codes when we can achieve it in one line of CSS3 code?

Comment: I said it with all respect, and do not mean to be rude by any means. I apologize if I sounded rude or mean.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. The gradient is simply generated by this tool - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's say that the already posted answers are good methods to achieve that (including a comment about z-index).

Anyway, if what the OP wnats is to set the gradient vertically, al that is needed is to change

```
to bottom
```

for

```
45 deg
```

Just be aware that the way to set the angle has changed in the last w3c specs, so the value will change from syntax to syntax.

Just experiment around ..